# TinyMCE - wrap multiple elements in one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce

I want to use `style_formats` in TinyMCE **4**. One `style_format` should wrap content into a well like this:

Before:

```
<p>Hello!</p>
<p>More stuff...</p>
```

After:

```
<div class="well">
  <p>Hello!</p>
  <p>More stuff...</p>
</div>
```

...but what I get is:

```
<div class="well">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div class="well">
  <p>More stuff...</p>
</div>
```

My `style_format` looks like this:

```
style_formats: [{
  title: 'Box',
  block: 'div',
  classes: "well"
}]
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way:

```
setup: function(ed) {
    ed.addButton('well', {
        title: 'Make Well',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
            var text = ed.selection.getContent({
                'format': 'html'
            });
            if (text && text.length > 0) {
                ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false,
                    '<div class="well">' + text + '</div>');
            }
        }
    });
},
toolbar: "well"
```

...just in case anybody needs it.